# Convert an array of uni code values into a string

Tags: javascript

I have written a function which can turn a string into an array of uni code values. Now i want a way of turning this array back into a string. I am using `String.fromCharCode()`

```js
    function rot13(str) {

      var string = str.toUpperCase();
      var myArray = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        myArray.push(string.charCodeAt([i]));
      }

      var b = String.fromCharCode(myArray);
      return b;
    }

    rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

I am not getting anything back?

(At a later date i am planning on adding 13 to each uni code in the array)

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(myArray);`  ... array as an argument ?????

Answer (score 0):

[`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) accepts a list of numbers as parameters, not an array. You can apply the array:

```js
function rot13(str) {

  var string = str.toUpperCase();
  var myArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    myArray.push(string.charCodeAt(i));
  }

  var b = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, myArray);
  return b;
}

console.log(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC"));
```

Or use ES6 spread:

```js
function rot13(str) {

  var string = str.toUpperCase();
  var myArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    myArray.push(string.charCodeAt(i));
  }

  var b = String.fromCharCode(...myArray);
  return b;
}

console.log(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are applying [`String.fromCharCode`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%60String.fromCharCode%60&oq=%60String.fromCharCode%60&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for an array instead, you need to provide the charCode as the argument.

You can achieve the result using [`String.fromCharCode`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%60String.fromCharCode%60&oq=%60String.fromCharCode%60&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) inside the for loop.

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var string = str.toUpperCase();
  var res='';
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    res += String.fromCharCode(string.charCodeAt([i]));
  }
  return res;
}

rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

---

Or provide an array of values as the arguments using [spread syntax(`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) or [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method.

Answer (score 0):

As per [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) documention, the method takes individual values as arguments, not array. You could you apply or use spread operator to get the work done.

```js
function rot13(str) {

  var string = str.toUpperCase();
  var myArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    myArray.push(string.charCodeAt([i]));
  }

  return String.fromCharCode(...myArray);
  //return b;
}

console.log(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `myArray.toString();`, it should convert array elements.

Comment: I think the point is getting the char codes, do some operation with them, and then convert the new ones back to a string.

Comment: @Oriol, just use `toString()` when all the needed manipulations are done